# Regular expression find matched between a string and a space

Tags: regex

I need to find out all words in a sentence that are between a $ and a space like this 
this is $abc $cde any $ety.

The result should be abc, cde and ety.

I tried this

```
'(?<=$$)(.*)(?=)'
```

but it shows some error. What is wrong in this or any new suggestions?

Comment: I take it there is a space after ety.  Guessing you want `(?<=\$)(.*?)(?=\s)`

Comment: `/\$(\w+)\b/`. What you all are missing is word boundary is not always space.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
\$(\w+)
```

As capturing groups, you'll get each of the words.

`\w` will match a-Z, 0-9 and _, if you want to match only letters, for instance, you can change to: `\$([a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: `\w` will also include `0-9` and `_`

Comment: I know, I chose \w since I don't know the domain of words that should be matched, it's just a matter of switching. - Edited to make this obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the question, each word (word contains only chars A-Za-z) must begin with `$` and have a space at the end.
The following regex will match such words -- `\$([A-Za-z])+` (there is a space at the end, which is hard to see due to the formatting here). If there are multiple spaces, you can use `+` (space before +, hard to see again due to formatting) at the end of the regex.

Then you can extract the first matching group (i.e. `$1`) as your matching word, and you need to do this in a loop till there are no more matches you can extract. That is something like --

```
while ($x =~ /\$([A-Za-z])+  /g) {
   // $1 is your match
}
```

If your word contains more than just chars, then you can use `\w` as mentioned by `pcalcao`, which will include both `0-9` and `_`

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
(?<=\$)([^\s]*)(?=\s)
```